# Autofac passing parameters

Tags: c#, autofac

Let's assume I have an IConfigurationService interface with a corresponding implementation:

```
public class JsonConfigurationService : IConfigurationService
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
public JsonConfigurationService(string filePath, ILoggingService loggingService)
```

I want to use Autofac for dependency injection but I am not really sure how to handle the constructor parameters for the JsonConfigurationService. For the ILoggingService I have already added a registration like this - so there is no problem:

```
builder.RegisterType<NlogService>().As<ILoggingService>();
```

But how can I provide the filePath parameter to the constructor of the JsonConfigurationService. I have read about the options like "NamedParameter", "TypedParameter" or "ResolvedParameter" but for all of them a bad feeling remains.

- NamedParameter: What if someone renames the parameter afterwards
- TypedParameter: If another parameter with same type was added afterwards
- ResolvedParamter: Hmmm mixture of both

Is there a better way to handle this or a kind of best practice?

Comment: is that value a constant in compile-time? is it resolved in run-time, if so, from where?

Comment: It is resolved during run-time

Comment: from where?....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `filePath` is known at compile-time there are a few options, but it really comes down to personal preference as they're all decent approaches with pros and cons. I'd at least recommend some basic unit tests covering resolution of key services just to be safe. With tests, using a NamedParameter might still not feel completely right but in a practical sense it's fine.

Another way would be to register using a lambda, e.g.

```
builder.Register(c => new JsonConfigurationService(@"c:\somepath\", c.Resolve<ILoggingService>()));
```

That obviously gets trickier if your `JsonConfigurationService` dependencies blow out but at least you get compile-time checking.

Another way is to abstract away the string behind another type and use a TypedParameter. Some would see it as unnecessary code but IMO if it helps with readability, even just in the context of registrations, it might be worth it:

```
public interface IFilePathProvider
{
    string FilePath { get; }
}
public class FilePathProvider : IFilePathProvider
{
    public string FilePath => @"c:\";
}


public JsonConfigurationService(IFilePathProvider filePathProvider, ILoggingService loggingService)
```

If you end up reading that parameter from config, or if it's used elsewhere in code, then that abstraction might even make sense in its own right.

It comes down to the specifics of the situation and a bit of preference - not sure there's a clear-cut best practice that covers every scenario.

EDIT - noting that the file path is determined at run-time it might be worth reading this: [Injecting Runtime Components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/). As per that, if it is only set at start-up, similar principles still apply. If the path is determined later then it's probably worth looking at removing it as a constructor parameter altogether.